# Not able to access label control (Placed in ItemTemplate) in code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to access label control (placed in ItemTemplate) in code behind file, but not able to do the same.
I am using following code:

```
        <asp:ListView ID="lvData" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1"
            OnPagePropertiesChanging="listView_PagePropertiesChanging">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table >
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <GroupTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </tr>
            </GroupTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProfileID" runat="server" Text="LB1000"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

In above code, the lblProfileID label should be accessible in code behind file.
I have written following code in C#, but it showing compile time error as "The name 'lblProfileID' does not exist in the current context".

```
    private void GetID()
    {
        string strID = lblProfileID.Text;
    }
```

Comment: This is markup. Where is your code?

Comment: C# code is added.

Comment: Look up the FindControl methods - there are numerous answers to this on SO

Comment: I have tried lvData.FindControl("lblProfileID") but it returns null.

Comment: We really need to see more of your code. Where are you calling the FindControl method? What are you using the OnPagePropertiesChanging handler for?:

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't see anything coming from a database and this begs the question: why are you using a ListView? You really need to ask a [meaningful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) question in a way that helps others understand exactly what problem you're trying to solve.

Here is the typical way you'd access a control in the ItemTemplate:

**Markup:**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvData" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1"
    OnPagePropertiesChanging="listView_PagePropertiesChanging" OnItemDataBound="ListView_ItemDataBound">
    ...
</asp:ListView>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
protected void ListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

        ....
        Label lblProfileID = e.Item.FindControl("lblProfileID") as Label;
        string strID = lblProfileID.Text;
        ...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You would use the method above to assign DB values to your label. You could also grab the value of the label in your GetID() method as follows:

```
private void GetID() 
{ 
    // First check if there is actually data being returned in an if statement
    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in lvData.Items) 
    {
        Label lblProfileID = e.Item.FindControl("lblProfileID") as Label;
        string strID = lblProfileID.Text;
    }    
}
```